# Nexus connectivity with maven 404 vs 501

Tags: repository, maven-2, nexus, sonatype, maven-central

From 15th Jan 2020, maven central location is now secured with https protocol. So, we understand that maven settings and pom.xml have to be updated in our repository location with https.

But there is a question how Nexus internally manages this, please could someone advise? - Our maven based java application has a dependency groupId:org.mule.modules and artifactId:mule-module-sfdc. This artifact was never available in http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/. After 15th Jan, without any of our change, we received 501 error through Nexus for URL - http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/mule/modules/mule-module-sfdc/8.0.0/mule-module-sfdc-8.0.0.pom

I am bit confused here, because the same location (with http or https) never had this artifact then why it failed after 15th Jan 2020?
Is it because Nexus ignores 404 error, but strictly fails for 501 error from maven central?

Answer (score 0):

Any request to Maven Central that does not use https will receive a 501 error, regardless of whether or not the file requested actually exists.  We chose 501 so that repositories in Nexus will enter "auto-block" mode, indicating that there is a problem with the connection. If you haven't already done so, switch to using https.

Comment: #rseddon - does that mean before 15th Jan 2020 when maven central returned 404 over http calls, Nexus used to ignore that? The reason is of asking this is - the artifact requested was never present in maven central before https thingy went live on 15th

Comment: Yes, nexus basically ignores 404 responses. For a bit more detail... it caches them for a period of time, so it won’t keep asking for things that don’t exist.